# How to make checkboxes displayed vertically instead of horizontally when they are implemented with ngFor?

Tags: angular, ngfor

I have created this checkbox list:
[image]

Using this simple html code:

```
  <label  *ngFor="let order of options">
    <input type="checkbox" >
    {{order}}
  </label>
```

And the following typescript code:

```
options: string[] = [
    "1 jour",
    "2-3 jours",
    "4-5 jours",
    "Plus d'une semaine",
    "Plus de 15 jours",
    "Un mois et plus"
  ];
```

I tried to display the checkboxes vertically (I.e: Stacked on each other instead of next to each other)  using the

> < br >

tag. But, it didn't work.
Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `*ngFor` with `ng-container` and insert `<br>` tag inside.

```html
<ng-container *ngFor="let order of options">
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" >
    {{order}}
  </label>  
  <br>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: Worked! Perfect! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

try wrapping it in a div and using [Flex display](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) and column.

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <label *ngFor="let order of options">
    <input type="checkbox" >
    {{order}}
  </label>  
</div>
```

and add the css class.

```
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

Try running the snippet below to illustrate the answer you are looking for, the html is very similar to what the `ngFor` will be creating in the DOM.

```css
.wrapper {
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" >
    1
  </label>  
  
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" >
    1
  </label>  
<div>
```

Answer (score 1):

No need for additional styles and no need for any page breaks. Just move your `*ngFor` structural directive in an enclosing `div` tag to make each item come in a new line as

```
<div *ngFor="let order of options">
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" >
        {{order}}
    </label>
</div>
```

A `div` is a block element which occupies 100% of the container width.

Stackblitz demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-newline-checkboxes